# Excel table: when hyperlink is added via VBA then hyperlinks are added to all rows in table

Tags: excel, vba

When I add the hyperlink to a table then the hyperlink gets repeated across all rows cells in a column.

```
url = "https://example.com/s/" & Sheets("config").Range("B9").Value & "/users/" & ws_import.Cells(i, ExportUsers.eUser_ID).Value
    
' this works
ws_user.Cells(x, DisableUsers.eName).Value = ws_import.Cells(i, ExportUsers.eUser_Name).Value ' Name

' repeat hyperlink in all rows cells  of the column

ws_user.Cells(x, DisableUsers.eName).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & url & """, """ & ws_import.Cells(i, ExportUsers.eUser_Name).Value & """)"
```

Without the table it works perfectly

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you're adding the formula:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
```

It should stop the table from auto filling it with formulas.

Make sure to enable it after you've entered the formulas with

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
```